# How to retain a alert dialog when android device is rotated

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, screen-orientation

Hi i am quite new to android.In my application I'm using an alert dialog and i want the alert dialog to be retained when the device is rotated from landscape to portrait and vice-versa.I'm using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to restore all other information but alert dialog is not getting retained.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the activity declaration in manifest, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This is not recommended but works fine. Read [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) for more information.